# iOS positioning and virtual keyboard

Tags: html, ios, css, virtual-keyboard

I have a  website which has 7-8 rows of divs  with position:static.  When I tap into an input field (which is a part of div) focus comes on the input and the virtual keyboard appears .The divs now scrolls up with keyboard but suddenly it goes down also. So a user is not able to see the text box in focus.

Please help me out on his Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?